# How do I create a "rank" column in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Given the first two columns, I need to create a "rank" column in excel (as shown below)

[image]

Can someone help me as to what the formula would look like to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel has a `rank` function:

- The first argument is the cell you want to rank
- The second argument is an array of cells to rank against (here it seems like all your data is between a2:a13, but adjust as needed)
- The third argument is the order. If it's 0 or omitted ranking would be in descending order, if it's 1 ranking will be in ascending order.

So, e.g., for the first cell:

```
=RANK(A2,$A$2:$A$13,1)
```

And then copy the function and adjust the first argument for all other cells.

Comment: Thanks so much!! Exactly what i wanted!

Comment: @Analytics Mark the question as answered Please visit the [Tour](https://superuser.com/tour) and [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers) to learn how to do it.